# Как обрезать путь к файлу через regex?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как можно получить только имя файла или папки через regex ?
Например у меня есть такой путь:

> templates/FolderName

и мне нужно получить только `FolderName`
А если передать такой путь :

> templates/FolderName/File.md

то нужно получить `File.md`

Как через regex матчить только то что после последнего `/`

Comment: `^.*\/([^\/]+)$`

Comment: а зачем именно через регулярку (просто интересно)?

Comment: Например так: `/^.*[\/\\]/g` или `path=path.split('/');` ну, а дальше `path[path.length-1];`

Answer (score 1):

Через Regex:

```js
var strWithFilename = "templates/FolderName/File.md";
var strWithPath = "templates/FolderName";


var fileName = strWithFilename.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
console.log(fileName);

var folderName = strWithPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
console.log(folderName);
```

---

**Дополнение**. Через JS без Regex (способ отличный от уже данного ответа):

```js
var strWithFilename = "templates/FolderName/File.md";
var strWithPath = "templates/FolderName";

var fileNameArr = strWithFilename.split("/");
var fileName = fileNameArr[fileNameArr.length - 1];
console.log(fileName);

var folderNameArr = strWithPath.split("/");
var folderName = folderNameArr[folderNameArr.length - 1];
console.log(folderName);
```

Ссылка на источник: [Get filename from string path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11805683/5275890)

Answer (score -1):

```js
var s = 'templates/FolderName/File.md';
console.log(s.split('/').pop());
```

`split` разобьет строку по указанному символу, `pop` извлечет последний элемент из полученного массива.

Comment: Лучше тогда уже использовать `s[s.length-1]`.

Comment: Чем лучше и для кого? `pop`, например, короче

Comment: `[]` вроде работают быстрее.

Comment: Вроде? Это критическое место в приложении? Где бенчмарк? Ну и в идеальном интерпретаторе варианты должны работать с одинаковой скоростью

Comment: Ну а вообще такой вариант уже есть и каждый выберет себе что посчитает нужным. Если у вас есть свой вариант – можете оформить его отдельным ответом и пояснить чем он лучше